# Hybrid model of a transistor

Tags: transistors

[image]

Can someone help me to find the hybrid pi model of such transistor configuration?
Assume Hfe = 90, the input voltage is applied in series with capacitor C2, (0.082uF) and Vout it from the red dot between C3 and R7 with respect to ground.
[image: Thats my 1st conclusion]

So, I came to this conclusion, Im not really worried about the input impedance, What Im worried how to calculate the voltage across R4 in the second drawing with respect to ground.

Comment: That right there looks like a homework question.  If you're hoping for an answer, you need to show us your attempt at solving.  Explain what you know and make a hypothesis that we can correct/verify.

Comment: Not a homework question, we talked before about another SQ decoding network, turned out I ended up giving up on such circuit and found a new one. It is full shown on this site http://art-and-technology.blogspot.com/2015/12/sq-quadraphonic-dead-surround-audio.html

Comment: I could just solder the components, and listen to the records, but I want to understand the workings, and, maybe, expand the frequency range on which it is supposed to be phase shiffint.

Comment: Anyway, to be more specific, Ill draw my conclusions and the point where I got stucked.

Comment: People will be more lenient with you if it isn't a homework question, but you may wish to include something to the effect of "I know that a hybrid pi model represents a circuit in *suchandsuch* a way, and I understand how *this piece* and *that piece* fit together but I'm not sure how to represent *that*".  Ideally people want enough information to know where your knowledge is lacking so they can tailor their response a bit to your needs/educational background.

Comment: Fair enough, Im recalculating the parameters, and, Ill show another drawing of where I gt stucked.

Comment: Just draw my conclusions.

Comment: What I havent understood is if any portion of the current from the current source, which is Hfe*Ib, go through R3(collector resistor) from picture 2?

Comment: You need to improve the clarity of where the sources are in both diagrams.  The giant Vin/Vout arrows aren't very clear.  To calculate voltage across R4, The source in the second diagram is showing an AC current of 1A at 440Hz.  Is this correct?  1A is actually quite a lot of current to run through a 2.7kOhm resistor.

Comment: No, the 1A value is just an arbitrary one, the correct value is Hfe*Ib, which goes through resistor R2 in picture 2.

Comment: Hybrid pi works for any bipolar circuit, at low frequencies.